# Configure AdonisJS to listen to HTTPS 4.1

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

i have added my ssl code in hook file

hook file code :

```
const { hooks }      = require('@adonisjs/ignitor')
const Helpers        = use('Helpers')
const Server         = use('Server')
const Env            = use('Env')
const https       = require('https')
const fs          = require('fs')
hooks.before.httpServer(() => {
  
        var certOptions = {
          key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/serverkey.key'),
          cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/servercrt.crt'),
        }
        return https.createServer(certOptions)
})
```

my server.js file code is i am calling hook in preload but ssl not working

```
new Ignitor(require('@adonisjs/fold'))
.appRoot(__dirname)
.preLoad('start/hook')
.fireHttpServer()
.catch(console.error)
```

Answer (score 0):

I

```js
const { Ignitor } = require('@adonisjs/ignitor')

// ::=======================================================================
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')

var certOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('./sslCert/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./sslCert/server.cer'),
}

// ::=======================================================================
new Ignitor(require('@adonisjs/fold'))
  .appRoot(__dirname)
  .fireHttpServer((handle) => {
    return https.createServer(certOptions, handle);
  })
  .catch(console.error)
```

used this code in adonis js 4.1 for http to https